# Function to check that a Python list contains only True and then only False

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to only allow lists where the first n elements are `True` and then all of the remaining elements are `False`. I want lists like these examples to return `True`:

- `[]`
- `[True]`
- `[False]`
- `[False, False]`
- `[True, False]`
- `[True, False, False]`
- `[True, True, True, False]`

And lists like these to return `False`:

- `[False, True]`
- `[True, False, True]`

That is, any list that can we written as `[True] * n + [False] * m` for `n`, `m` integers in the interval [0, infty).

I am currently using a function called `check_true_then_false`, but I feel like there is probably a neater way of doing this. The code doesn't need to be fast, as this will only be run once (not inside a loop) and the lists will short (single digit lengths).

```
def check_true_then_false(x):
    n_trues = sum(x)
    should_be_true = x[:n_trues]  # get the first n items
    should_be_false = x[n_trues:len(x)]  # get the remaining items
    # return True only if all of the first n elements are True and the remaining
    # elements are all False
    return all(should_be_true) and not any(should_be_false)
```

Testing shows that it produces the correct output:

```
test_cases = [[True],
              [False],
              [True, False],
              [True, False, False],
              [True, True, True, False],
              [False, True],
              [True, False, True]]
print([check_true_then_false(test_case) for test_case in test_cases])
# expected output: [True, True, True, True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out. Try again on SO. I have a concrete answer I'd like to post that I think would work for this site, but would also work for SO.

Comment: Ping me if you decide to make the post again.

Comment: I've just removed this question from SO because I was told it was better suited to Code Review, so I don't know where to post it anymore.

Comment: Perhaps reword it slightly. SO would be fine if you had a particular problem to solve. For example, instead of "how do I do it better", ask "can I do it without making the two temp lists". That would be completely on topic and I'd provide you with an answer almost immediately. The issue before was that you had working code but were generally hoping to "improve" it. If you have a very specific topic of improvement, SO will welcome your question.

Comment: Could you clarify the requirements? Are `[]`, `[True]`, and `[False, False]` acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I've added `[]` to the question as acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: Another way of explaining is any list that can we written as `[True] * n + [False] * m` for `n`, `m` integers in the interval [0, infty).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- You can just use `x[n_trues:]` rather than `x[n_trues:len(x)]`.
- Your comments don't really say more than the code. And so I'd recommend removing the comments.
- If you want to keep your code documented use docstrings, which can be exported to your documentation via tools like Sphinx.
- As commented by [Konrad Rudolph](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/308/konrad-rudolph), you can remove the `and not any(should_be_false)` as this will always fail if the `all` fails.

```
def check_true_then_false(x):
    """Check first n values are True and the rest are False."""
    return all(x[:sum(x)])
```

---

If you want your code to work with iterators, not just sequences then you can instead use:

```
def check_true_then_false(it):
    """Check first n values are True and the rest are False."""
    it = iter(it)
    # Takes advantage of the iterating side effect, where it consumes the iterator.
    # This allows `all` to simultaneously checks `it` starts with trues and advances `it`.
    return all(it) or not any(it)
```

For the following two inputs `all` will result in:

```
>>> all([True] * n)
True
>>> all([True] * n + [False, ...])
False
```

However it will mean that `it` is still `[...]` as `all` and `any` are lazy. Meaning that we just need to check the rest are false. Meaning `all` slices the iterator for you without you having to. Leaving `any` with:

```
>>> any([False] * n)
False
>>> any([False] * n + [True, ...])
True
```

Comment: `all(it) or not any(it)` is elegant! – It would detect `["a", "b"]` as a valid list because it checks for truthiness rather than True/False, but from the Python point of view that is probably the “right thing.”

Comment: Elegant but cryptic. I would be wary of using it in actual code. In the first bit of code (as in OP’s), you can omit the redundant test for `and not any(…)` (assuming the list only contains bools).

Comment: @KonradRudolph True, and true. I guess using a comment to decryptify it may help.

Comment: In the comment, instead of saying `and slices it` I would use the phrasing `and advances it`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yeah, that's probably a better way to describe it :)

Comment: That all/any trick is a beautiful and hideous hack! To get the same single pass effect more readably, perhaps use dropwhile from itertools. E.g. `not any(itertools.dropwhile(bool, x))`

Comment: I prefer Josiah's suggestion to use `not any(itertools.dropwhile(bool, x))`. Using `all` makes use of (IMO, abuses) the implementation details of functions, while not being reflective of their intended semantic meanings. OTOH, using `dropwhile` does not assume any implementation details for correctness; each function is used consistently with its intended purpose.

Comment: Your fourth point will cause the function to fail on `[True, False, True, -1]`.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Yeah, the question said it only works with booleans, and so I didn't go out of my way to make it work with anything else

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you want your list of booleans to be sorted.

Specifically, since `True > False`, you want your list to be sorted in decreasing order:

```
def check_true_then_false(booleans):
    return booleans == sorted(booleans, reverse=True)
```

Done!

```
>>> test_cases = [[True],
...               [False],
...               [True, False],
...               [True, False, False],
...               [True, True, True, False],
...               [False, True],
...               [True, False, True]]
>>> 
>>> print([check_true_then_false(test_case) for test_case in test_cases])
[True, True, True, True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: This is a good answer as it expresses a higher level property of the desired code. The code is clearer because you get the "why", instead of just the "how", from reading it.

Comment: It may be more obvious if there is a `partitioned(...)` function in Python (I don't know Python that well, but C++ has [`std::is_partitioned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_partitioned)). It's a bit tricky to think of `sorted`, as you wouldn't want to sort a list to create this pattern due to partitioning being a simpler algorithm.

Comment: @Justin: You're right that `sorted` is a minimal overkill. `is_partitioned` doesn't exist in standard Python as far as I know. Also, partition isn't enough : `True`s should appear before `False`s.

Comment: @EricDuminil Any decent partition implementation should take a predicate that allows you to specify how to partition it. Also, FWIW, C++'s `std::partition` moves `true` elements before `false` elements.

Comment: @Justin: Please ignore my last comment then. I learned something today.

Comment: Downvoter : constructive criticism is welcome!

Comment: Downvote is fundamentally because it is purely an alternative implementation, and not a review of the posted code.

Comment: I'd also note that it's also not a very efficient implementation, adding at least an input length memory allocation and a sort to what is fundamentally an in place single pass problem, and it doesn't even have the elegance of being obvious at a glance why it works.

Comment: @Josiah: Thanks a lot for the constructive criticism, I understand your point. It's indeed an overkill to sort a list to check if it's sorted. Still, OP wrote `I feel like there is probably a neater way of doing this. The code doesn't need to be fast, as this will only be run once and the lists will short.` so `O(n.log(n))` shouldn't be much of a problem IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Your code works correctly under the assumption that the given list
contains only `True` or `False` elements. For other lists it can return
“false positives”

```
>>> check_true_then_false([1, 1, 0])
True
```

or abort with a runtime error:

```
>>> check_true_then_false(["a", "b"])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

The function traverses the given list in order to find the number of
`True` elements. It then creates two additional lists, which are also
traversed to check if all elements are `True` resp. `False`.

A more efficient way would be to iterate the given list only once:

- Find the first non-`True` element. If there is any then it must be `False`.
- Then find the next non-`False` element. There should not be any.

If either of the above iterations fails (and `next()` raises a
`StopIteration` exception) then the list *is* of the required form, and
the function returns `True`:

```
def check_true_then_false(x):
    list_iter = iter(x)
    try:
        return (next(elem for elem in list_iter if elem is not True) is False
            and next(elem for elem in list_iter if elem is not False) is False)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
```

Peilonrayz [explained](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/203083/35991) how to document the
function using docstrings. In addition, the test cases can also be
embedded into the docstrings, with [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html):

```
def check_true_then_false(x):
    """Check first n values are True and the rest are False.

    >>> check_true_then_false([True])
    True
    >>> check_true_then_false([False])
    True
    >>> check_true_then_false([False, True])
    False
    >>> check_true_then_false([True, False, True])
    False
    >>> check_true_then_false([1, 1, 0])
    False
    >>> check_true_then_false(["a", "b"])
    False

    """
    # ... Your code ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: This doesn’t correctly detect non-boolean values if the first non-True argument is not False. For example: `check_true_then_false([True, True, "foo", False])` evaluates to True.

Comment: @NeilRoberts: You are right (because `next()` consumes that element). It should be fixed now (but lacks the elegance of Peilonrayz's solution).